# opencv - how to return comparison matrix with same type as compared matrices

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

The openCV documentation on [cv::compare](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare) states that the output array (dst in the function description) is the same size and type as the 2 input arrays being compared.
This is not what I see as it always return a UINT8 matrix with '255' as the logical 1, and '0' for logical 0.
Let's take for example, 2 matrices of type CV_32FC1 that have identical data and run the following code:

```
cv::compare(I, J, dst, cv::CMP_EQ);
```

The result is a UINT8 matrix full of '255'.

1. Why does this differ from the description?
2. Is it possible to return a logical matrix with '1' for logical 1 and '0' for logical 0 and the same type as the input matrices (without using convertTo on the output matrix followed by division by 255)?
3. How does the answer to questions 1-2 change if we're discussing oclMat matrices?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't differ from the explanation if you look lower down it says

> When the comparison result is true, the corresponding element of output array is set to 255.

Take a look at matrix expressions you should be able to scale or do boolean multiplication on the array.[Expressions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions)

Edit: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/a7160d9b128fed82e4eea728ceb95eab1b085f00 There is no way to change this it is working as intended as per this documentation update.

Comment: It does differ in Mat *type* - it returns a UINT8 Mat no matter what the input matrices are and this requires an extra step of converting the logical matrix in order to multiply it with one of the input matrices (a common thing I'd like to do in order to zero out all elements in the input matrix that don't comply with the comparison condition).

Comment: You were right unfortunately I don't have a solution for you as it turns out the docs were out of date see this commit here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/a7160d9b128fed82e4eea728ceb95eab1b085f00 which says that it is working as written.